# When is $L^2(\nu) \cap L^2(\mu)$ dense in $L^2(\mu)$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma)$ be some measurable space with measures $\nu$ and $\mu$.
So long as $\nu \ll \mu$ it makes sense to think of $L^2(\mu) \cap L^2(\nu)$ as a subspace of $L^2(\mu)$ since they'll have the same underlying set. Is there a general criteria for $L^2(\nu)$ to actually be dense in $L^2(\mu)$? What if we specialise to the case $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure?

Edit: To provide some motivation, I'm wondering in which situations it makes sense to define $-\Delta + V$ as an unbounded operator on a Hilbert space where $V$ is a multiplication operator. $-\Delta$ naturally acts on $H^1$ as an unbounded operator and I'm wondering if there's a general criterion on $V$ so that $L^2( V(x) dx )$ is dense in $L^2$.

Comment: I suspect this question came up in your research? Could you please edit your question to include some motivation?

Comment: Many (all?) of the standard potentials $V$ that arise are atleast in $L^1_{loc}$, and so smooth compactly supported functions lie in $L^2(V\,dx)$, and so $L^2(V\,dx)\cap L^2$ is dense in $L^2$.

Comment: In fact, more generally, one could simply look at simple functions on arbitrary measure spaces as the easier dense subcollection. So as long as every $\mu$-finite measure set is also $\nu$-finite, it seems like the argument goes through (this is weaker than your original assumption because in the absolutely continuous case, the Radon-Nikodym derivative is $\mu$ locally-integrable if I recall correctly).